# Emulator is closing while Minimising Android studio. Not showing its Case

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, android-emulator

Emulator is closing while closing Android studio .Also not floating freely

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using Android studio Hedgehog you can use the window icon to detach the emulator from Android Studio UI.

[image]

Or you can use the CLI to launch a emulator which will work totally without launching Android Studio

```
 ~/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/emulator @Pixel_5_API_32 -verbose
```